# How can I easily download this videos from this site?

Tags: download, youtube

This Videos are hosted from Youtube but when I try to watch them on Youtube they are not available in Youtube.

http://dts.aisc.org/courses/dts/modules/1a.html

Currently I am downloading files by individually clicking on them and when the IDM download video button appears on the Video I just click it to download but the problem is initially the video quality is only 480p but I need to download in 720p.

Comment: Search Google for `youtube-dl`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Interesting downloader but it isn't clear how that solves the problem of downloading the 720p version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like they are viewable on YouTube as well.

As an example, here is the video from your link, but on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkMKGN5DNlw&feature=youtu.be

**Location**

Depending on your location, it might be that the video is not available in your country, but you can work around that by using a proxy.

**Downloading**

There are many tools for downloading videos from YouTube. As an example, [here are some plugins for Chrome](https://www.google.no/search?q=youtube%20download%20plugin&oq=youtube%20download%20plugin) that you can use.

Same strategy for finding tools if you're using another browser.

Comment: Thnx... But is there a way where I can just copy the link of the youtube video from the buttons and automatically download them from the link?

Comment: @RonyShawkat you can rightclick on the video and choose "[copy video URL](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wMEGW.png)"

Comment: Yes I can do that but there are hundreds of videos I want to download from that site and it will be a very tiresome job to go through all the links manually and right clicking them for the link. I wanted an automated or semi automated system... :(

Comment: You question does not reflect that.